# Duvida em Procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server

Pessoal fiz uma função em SQLServer que faz o controle de um gráfico para mim em C#, essa função me traz todos os alunos de uma referente escola.
A função é a seguinte:

```
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
    GO
    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GRF_DESEMPENHO_ANUAL](@P_GMUNICIPIO_ID INT, @P_EDEMPRESA_ID INT,         @P_SECRETARIA_ID INT, @P_ANO CHAR(4), @P_ESCOLA_ID INT, @P_CURSO_ID INT, @P_MODALIDADE_ID    INT, @P_SERIE_ID INT, @P_TURNO_ID INT, @P_TURMA_ID INT, @P_VALOR_ZERO CHAR(1))
    RETURNS @SWT_GRF_DESEMPENHO_ANUAL TABLE
    (
    EDEMPRESA_ID INT,
    EMPRESA CHAR(60),
    GMUNICIPIO_ID INT,
    MUNICIPIO CHAR(40),
    SECRETARIA_ID INT,
    SECRETARIA CHAR(50),
    ANO CHAR(4),
    ESCOLA_ID INT,
    ESCOLA VARCHAR(150),
    CURSO_ID INT,
    CURSO CHAR(100),
    MODALIDADE_ID INT,
    MODALIDADE CHAR(100),
    SERIE_ID INT,
    SERIE_FORMAT CHAR(30),
    TURMA_ID INT,
    LEGENDA CHAR(2),
    TURNO_ID INT,
    TURNO CHAR(20),
    SITUACAO VARCHAR(25),
    TOTAL INT,
    TOTAL_GERAL INT,
    TOTAL_REAL INT
    )
AS
BEGIN 
   DECLARE @V_SERIE_HIST CHAR(3)
   DECLARE @V_GRAU CHAR(2)
   DECLARE @EDEMPRESA_ID INT
   DECLARE @EMPRESA CHAR(60)
   DECLARE @GMUNICIPIO_ID INT
   DECLARE @MUNICIPIO CHAR(40)
   DECLARE @SECRETARIA_ID INT
   DECLARE @SECRETARIA CHAR(50)
   DECLARE @ANO CHAR(4)
   DECLARE @ESCOLA_ID INT
   DECLARE @ESCOLA VARCHAR(150)
   DECLARE @CURSO_ID INT
   DECLARE @CURSO CHAR(100)
   DECLARE @MODALIDADE_ID INT
   DECLARE @MODALIDADE CHAR(100)
   DECLARE @SERIE_ID INT
   DECLARE @SERIE_FORMAT CHAR(30)
   DECLARE @TURMA_ID INT
   DECLARE @LEGENDA CHAR(2)
   DECLARE @TURNO_ID INT
   DECLARE @TURNO CHAR(20)
   DECLARE @SITUACAO VARCHAR(25)
   DECLARE @TOTAL INT
   DECLARE @TOTAL_GERAL INT
   DECLARE @TOTAL_REAL INT
   DECLARE @SWV_cursor_var1 CURSOR

DECLARE @SWV_cursor_var2 CURSOR
      SET @SWV_cursor_var1 = CURSOR  
   FOR SELECT M.ESCOLA_ID, E.ESCOLA, M.SERIE_ID, S.SERIE_HIST, M.TURMA_ID,
           M.TURNO_ID, TN.TURNO, M.EDEMPRESA_ID, M.GMUNICIPIO_ID, M.ANO,
           M.SECRETARIA_ID, EM.EMPRESA, MU.MUNICIPIO, SE.SECRETARIA, S.GRAU,
           S.MODALIDADE_ID, TM.LEGENDA, S.CURSO_ID, CM.MODALIDADE, C.CURSO
   FROM ED_MATRICUL M
   LEFT JOIN ED_ESCOLAS E ON (M.EDEMPRESA_ID = E.EDEMPRESA_ID)
   AND (M.GMUNICIPIO_ID = E.GMUNICIPIO_ID) AND (M.SECRETARIA_ID = E.SECRETARIA_ID)
   AND (M.ESCOLA_ID = E.ESCOLA_ID)
   LEFT JOIN ED_SERIES S ON (M.EDEMPRESA_ID = S.EDEMPRESA_ID)
   AND (M.GMUNICIPIO_ID = S.GMUNICIPIO_ID) AND (M.SECRETARIA_ID = S.SECRETARIA_ID)
   AND (M.SERIE_ID = S.SERIE_ID)
   LEFT JOIN ED_CURSOMODALIDADE CM ON (S.EDEMPRESA_ID = CM.EDEMPRESA_ID)
   AND (S.GMUNICIPIO_ID = CM.GMUNICIPIO_ID) AND (S.SECRETARIA_ID = CM.SECRETARIA_ID)
   AND (S.CURSO_ID = CM.CURSO_ID) AND (S.MODALIDADE_ID = CM.MODALIDADE_ID)
   LEFT JOIN ED_CURSO C ON (S.EDEMPRESA_ID = C.EDEMPRESA_ID)
   AND (S.GMUNICIPIO_ID = C.GMUNICIPIO_ID) AND (S.SECRETARIA_ID = C.SECRETARIA_ID)
   AND (S.CURSO_ID = C.CURSO_ID)
   LEFT JOIN ED_TURMAS TM ON (M.EDEMPRESA_ID = TM.EDEMPRESA_ID)
   AND (M.GMUNICIPIO_ID = TM.GMUNICIPIO_ID) AND (M.SECRETARIA_ID = TM.SECRETARIA_ID)
   AND (M.ESCOLA_ID = TM.ESCOLA_ID) AND (M.SERIE_ID = TM.SERIE_ID)
   AND (M.TURNO_ID = TM.TURNO_ID) AND (M.ANO = TM.ANO) AND (M.TURMA_ID = TM.TURMA_ID)
   LEFT JOIN ED_TURNO TN ON (M.EDEMPRESA_ID = TN.EDEMPRESA_ID)
   AND (M.GMUNICIPIO_ID = TN.GMUNICIPIO_ID) AND (M.SECRETARIA_ID = TN.SECRETARIA_ID)
   AND (M.TURNO_ID = TN.TURNO_ID)
   LEFT JOIN ED_SECRETARIA SE ON (M.EDEMPRESA_ID = SE.EDEMPRESA_ID)
   AND (M.GMUNICIPIO_ID = SE.GMUNICIPIO_ID) AND (M.SECRETARIA_ID = SE.SECRETARIA_ID)
   LEFT JOIN ED_EMPRESA EM ON (SE.EDEMPRESA_ID = EM.EDEMPRESA_ID)
   LEFT JOIN GMUNICIPIO MU ON (SE.GMUNICIPIO_ID = MU.GMUNICIPIO_ID)
   WHERE ((M.GMUNICIPIO_ID = @P_GMUNICIPIO_ID) OR (@P_GMUNICIPIO_ID IS NULL))
   AND ((M.EDEMPRESA_ID = @P_EDEMPRESA_ID) OR (@P_EDEMPRESA_ID IS NULL))
   AND ((M.SECRETARIA_ID = @P_SECRETARIA_ID) OR (@P_SECRETARIA_ID IS NULL))
   AND M.ANO = @P_ANO
   AND ((M.ESCOLA_ID = @P_ESCOLA_ID) OR (@P_ESCOLA_ID IS NULL))
   AND ((S.CURSO_ID = @P_CURSO_ID) OR (@P_CURSO_ID IS NULL))
   AND ((S.MODALIDADE_ID = @P_MODALIDADE_ID) OR (@P_MODALIDADE_ID IS NULL))
   AND ((M.SERIE_ID = @P_SERIE_ID) OR (@P_SERIE_ID IS NULL))
   AND ((M.TURNO_ID = @P_TURNO_ID) OR (@P_TURNO_ID IS NULL))
   AND ((M.TURMA_ID = @P_TURMA_ID) OR (@P_TURMA_ID IS NULL))
   GROUP BY M.ESCOLA_ID,E.ESCOLA,M.SERIE_ID,S.SERIE_HIST,M.TURMA_ID,M.TURNO_ID,TN.TURNO, 
   M.EDEMPRESA_ID,M.GMUNICIPIO_ID,M.ANO,M.SECRETARIA_ID,EM.EMPRESA, 
   MU.MUNICIPIO,SE.SECRETARIA,S.GRAU,S.MODALIDADE_ID,TM.LEGENDA,S.CURSO_ID, 
   CM.MODALIDADE,C.CURSO
   ORDER BY M.EDEMPRESA_ID,M.GMUNICIPIO_ID,M.SECRETARIA_ID,M.ESCOLA_ID,S.CURSO_ID, 
   S.MODALIDADE_ID,M.SERIE_ID,M.TURNO_ID,M.TURMA_ID
   OPEN @SWV_cursor_var1
   FETCH NEXT FROM @SWV_cursor_var1 INTO @ESCOLA_ID,@ESCOLA,@SERIE_ID,@V_SERIE_HIST,@TURMA_ID,@TURNO_ID,@TURNO,
   @EDEMPRESA_ID,@GMUNICIPIO_ID,@ANO,@SECRETARIA_ID,@EMPRESA,@MUNICIPIO,@SECRETARIA, 
   @V_GRAU,@MODALIDADE_ID,@LEGENDA,@CURSO_ID,@MODALIDADE,@CURSO
   while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   begin
      SELECT   @SERIE_FORMAT = SERIE_FORMAT FROM SERIE_HISTORICO(@V_SERIE_HIST,@V_GRAU) AS SERIE_HISTORICO

      SET @TOTAL_REAL = 0
      SELECT   @TOTAL_REAL = COUNT(1) FROM ED_MATRICUL M
      WHERE M.EDEMPRESA_ID = @EDEMPRESA_ID
      AND M.GMUNICIPIO_ID = @GMUNICIPIO_ID
      AND M.SECRETARIA_ID = @SECRETARIA_ID
      AND M.ANO = @ANO
      AND M.ESCOLA_ID = @ESCOLA_ID
      AND M.SERIE_ID = @SERIE_ID
      AND M.TURNO_ID = @TURNO_ID
      AND M.TURMA_ID = @TURMA_ID
      AND M.SITUACAO = '0'

      SET @TOTAL_GERAL = 0
      SELECT   @TOTAL_GERAL = COUNT(1) FROM ED_MATRICUL M
            LEFT JOIN ED_FIC_IND F ON (M.EDEMPRESA_ID = F.EDEMPRESA_ID)
      AND (M.GMUNICIPIO_ID = F.GMUNICIPIO_ID) AND (M.SECRETARIA_ID = F.SECRETARIA_ID)
      AND (M.MATRICULA_ID = F.MATRICULA_ID)
      WHERE M.EDEMPRESA_ID = @EDEMPRESA_ID
      AND M.GMUNICIPIO_ID = @GMUNICIPIO_ID
      AND M.SECRETARIA_ID = @SECRETARIA_ID
      AND M.ANO = @ANO
      AND M.ESCOLA_ID = @ESCOLA_ID
      AND M.SERIE_ID = @SERIE_ID
      AND M.TURNO_ID = @TURNO_ID
      AND M.TURMA_ID = @TURMA_ID
      AND M.SITUACAO not in ('5')


      SET @SWV_cursor_var2 = CURSOR  
      FOR SELECT CAST('Aprovados' AS VARCHAR(25)) AS SITUACAO, COUNT(1) AS TOTAL
      FROM ED_MATRICUL M
      LEFT JOIN ED_FIC_IND F ON (M.EDEMPRESA_ID = F.EDEMPRESA_ID)
      AND (M.GMUNICIPIO_ID = F.GMUNICIPIO_ID) AND (M.SECRETARIA_ID = F.SECRETARIA_ID)
      AND (M.MATRICULA_ID = F.MATRICULA_ID)
      WHERE M.EDEMPRESA_ID = @EDEMPRESA_ID
      AND M.GMUNICIPIO_ID = @GMUNICIPIO_ID
      AND M.SECRETARIA_ID = @SECRETARIA_ID
      AND M.ANO = @ANO
      AND M.ESCOLA_ID = @ESCOLA_ID
      AND M.SERIE_ID = @SERIE_ID
      AND M.TURNO_ID = @TURNO_ID
      AND M.TURMA_ID = @TURMA_ID
      AND M.SITUACAO = '0'
      AND F.SITU_FINAL = 'S' UNION ALL SELECT CAST('Rep. Desempenho' AS VARCHAR(25)), COUNT(1)
      FROM ED_MATRICUL M
      LEFT JOIN ED_FIC_IND F ON (M.EDEMPRESA_ID = F.EDEMPRESA_ID)
      AND (M.GMUNICIPIO_ID = F.GMUNICIPIO_ID) AND (M.SECRETARIA_ID = F.SECRETARIA_ID)
      AND (M.MATRICULA_ID = F.MATRICULA_ID)
      WHERE M.EDEMPRESA_ID = @EDEMPRESA_ID
      AND M.GMUNICIPIO_ID = @GMUNICIPIO_ID
      AND M.SECRETARIA_ID = @SECRETARIA_ID
      AND M.ANO = @ANO
      AND M.ESCOLA_ID = @ESCOLA_ID
      AND M.SERIE_ID = @SERIE_ID
      AND M.TURNO_ID = @TURNO_ID
      AND M.TURMA_ID = @TURMA_ID
      AND M.SITUACAO = '0'
      AND F.SITU_FINAL = 'N' UNION ALL SELECT CAST('Rep. Falta' AS VARCHAR(25)), COUNT(1)
      FROM ED_MATRICUL M
      LEFT JOIN ED_FIC_IND F ON (M.EDEMPRESA_ID = F.EDEMPRESA_ID)
      AND (M.GMUNICIPIO_ID = F.GMUNICIPIO_ID) AND (M.SECRETARIA_ID = F.SECRETARIA_ID)
      AND (M.MATRICULA_ID = F.MATRICULA_ID)
      WHERE M.EDEMPRESA_ID = @EDEMPRESA_ID
      AND M.GMUNICIPIO_ID = @GMUNICIPIO_ID
      AND M.SECRETARIA_ID = @SECRETARIA_ID
      AND M.ANO = @ANO
      AND M.ESCOLA_ID = @ESCOLA_ID
      AND M.SERIE_ID = @SERIE_ID
      AND M.TURNO_ID = @TURNO_ID
      AND M.TURMA_ID = @TURMA_ID
      AND M.SITUACAO = '0'
      AND F.SITU_FINAL = 'F' UNION ALL SELECT CAST('Transf. Rede' AS VARCHAR(25)), COUNT(1)
      FROM ED_MATRICUL M
      WHERE M.EDEMPRESA_ID = @EDEMPRESA_ID
      AND M.GMUNICIPIO_ID = @GMUNICIPIO_ID
      AND M.SECRETARIA_ID = @SECRETARIA_ID
      AND M.ANO = @ANO
      AND M.ESCOLA_ID = @ESCOLA_ID
      AND M.SERIE_ID = @SERIE_ID
      AND M.TURNO_ID = @TURNO_ID
      AND M.TURMA_ID = @TURMA_ID
      AND M.SITUACAO = '3' UNION ALL SELECT CAST('Transf. Int.' AS VARCHAR(25)), COUNT(1)
      FROM ED_MATRICUL M
      WHERE M.EDEMPRESA_ID = @EDEMPRESA_ID
      AND M.GMUNICIPIO_ID = @GMUNICIPIO_ID
      AND M.SECRETARIA_ID = @SECRETARIA_ID
      AND M.ANO = @ANO
      AND M.ESCOLA_ID = @ESCOLA_ID
      AND M.SERIE_ID = @SERIE_ID
      AND M.TURNO_ID = @TURNO_ID
      AND M.TURMA_ID = @TURMA_ID
      AND M.SITUACAO = '1' UNION ALL SELECT CAST('Desistente' AS VARCHAR(25)), COUNT(1)
      FROM ED_MATRICUL M
      WHERE M.EDEMPRESA_ID = @EDEMPRESA_ID
      AND M.GMUNICIPIO_ID = @GMUNICIPIO_ID
      AND M.SECRETARIA_ID = @SECRETARIA_ID
      AND M.ANO = @ANO
      AND M.ESCOLA_ID = @ESCOLA_ID
      AND M.SERIE_ID = @SERIE_ID
      AND M.TURNO_ID = @TURNO_ID
      AND M.TURMA_ID = @TURMA_ID
      AND M.SITUACAO = '4' 
 OPEN @SWV_cursor_var2
      FETCH NEXT FROM @SWV_cursor_var2 INTO @SITUACAO,@TOTAL
      while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
      begin

         IF (@P_VALOR_ZERO = '0')
             BEGIN
                IF (@TOTAL > 0)
                    INSERT INTO @SWT_GRF_DESEMPENHO_ANUAL VALUES(@EDEMPRESA_ID, @EMPRESA, @GMUNICIPIO_ID, @MUNICIPIO, @SECRETARIA_ID, @SECRETARIA, @ANO, @ESCOLA_ID, @ESCOLA, @CURSO_ID, @CURSO, @MODALIDADE_ID, @MODALIDADE, @SERIE_ID, @SERIE_FORMAT, @TURMA_ID, @LEGENDA, @TURNO_ID, @TURNO, @SITUACAO, @TOTAL, @TOTAL_GERAL, @TOTAL_REAL)
             END
         ELSE IF (@P_VALOR_ZERO = '1')

                INSERT INTO @SWT_GRF_DESEMPENHO_ANUAL VALUES(@EDEMPRESA_ID, @EMPRESA, @GMUNICIPIO_ID, @MUNICIPIO, @SECRETARIA_ID, @SECRETARIA, @ANO, @ESCOLA_ID, @ESCOLA, @CURSO_ID, @CURSO, @MODALIDADE_ID, @MODALIDADE, @SERIE_ID, @SERIE_FORMAT, @TURMA_ID, @LEGENDA, @TURNO_ID, @TURNO, @SITUACAO, @TOTAL, @TOTAL_GERAL, @TOTAL_REAL)

         SET @TOTAL_GERAL = 0 
         SET @TOTAL_REAL = 0

         FETCH NEXT FROM @SWV_cursor_var2 INTO @SITUACAO,@TOTAL
      end
      CLOSE @SWV_cursor_var2
      DEALLOCATE @SWV_cursor_var2
      FETCH NEXT FROM @SWV_cursor_var1 INTO @ESCOLA_ID,@ESCOLA,@SERIE_ID,@V_SERIE_HIST,@TURMA_ID,@TURNO_ID,@TURNO,
      @EDEMPRESA_ID,@GMUNICIPIO_ID,@ANO,@SECRETARIA_ID,@EMPRESA,@MUNICIPIO,@SECRETARIA, 
      @V_GRAU,@MODALIDADE_ID,@LEGENDA,@CURSO_ID,@MODALIDADE,@CURSO
   end
   CLOSE @SWV_cursor_var1
   DEALLOCATE @SWV_cursor_var1
RETURN
END
```

Quando eu seto 0 para a variável @P_VALOR_ZERO, me traz o valores corretos, porem quando passo o valor 1 traz valor errado, como faço para o valor 1 trazer os mesmos valores de quando eu passar o valor 0 ?
Detalhe: ao passar o valor 0, o grafico é exibido somente quando tiver valor acima de 0, quando eu passo o valor 1 ele exibe tudo, até mesmo os valores = 0, porem ele soma algo quando passo valor 0 e me traz valores errados.

Comment: Eu não tenho tempo para analisar todo código, mas me parece que o erro não está nessa variável e sim em outro lugar. Ela só é usada ali nos `IFs` e eles estão corretos. Mas tem outras coisas estranhas, por exemplo, esse `SET @TOTAL_GERAL = 0` perdido ali no cursor interno.

Comment: Verdade, ele nao precisaria estar ali, porém nao influencia nada, por exemplo, quando eu passo o valor 0, ele me traz todos os gráficos de turmas que tem mais que 0 alunos para exibir no gráfico, gerando para mim um total geral de 279 e real de 196 o que está correto, porem quando eu coloco o valor como 1, ele me traz os mesmos valores e mais outro gráfico zerado para mostrar tudo, porem com um total geral de 425 e real de 325, isso que nao entendo o pq, sendo que ele não faz soma nenhuma de nada quando eu seto o valor como 1... mas obrigado por enquanto.

Comment: O problema não é o parâmetro. Talvez seja que o gráfico ou o total que está somando o valor incorreto. Note que você insere o valor total real e o geral mesmo quando o total é zero. Então, se você somar o valor total de todos os registros, vai dar diferente mesmo. Precisa gravar o valor total geral e real para cada linha da tabela?

Comment: Não pode ser diferente pelo seguinte. Quando eu executo a procedure me da as seguintes informações 
Aprovados - 191 alunos
Desistente - 7 Alunos
Rep. Desempenho - 5 Alunos
Transf. Int. - 14 Alunos
Transf. Rede - 77 Alunos
Quando eu executo com o parametro 1 ele me traz essas mesmas linhas e mais uma que é Reprovado por Faltas - 0 Alunos, entao como ele soma diferente se os valores são iguais?

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece porque os valores individuais estão no primeiro cursor, e os totais no segundo. Repare que esta linha:

```
INSERT INTO @SWT_GRF_DESEMPENHO_ANUAL VALUES(@EDEMPRESA_ID, @EMPRESA, @GMUNICIPIO_ID, @MUNICIPIO, @SECRETARIA_ID, @SECRETARIA, @ANO, @ESCOLA_ID, @ESCOLA, @CURSO_ID, @CURSO, @MODALIDADE_ID, @MODALIDADE, @SERIE_ID, @SERIE_FORMAT, @TURMA_ID, @LEGENDA, @TURNO_ID, @TURNO, @SITUACAO, @TOTAL, @TOTAL_GERAL, @TOTAL_REAL)
```

E esta linha

```
FETCH NEXT FROM @SWV_cursor_var2 INTO @SITUACAO,@TOTAL
```

são independentes.

Neste caso, a lógica deve ser mudada para que `@TOTAL` também não seja atribuída quando o parâmetro da procedure não solicitar valores zerados.

Comment: O que não consigo entender é: se (@P_VALOR_ZERO = '0') ele faz outra condição e insere na tabela somente se IF (@TOTAL > 0), se eu fizer isso no outro if (@P_VALOR_ZERO = '1') dará certo, porém não mostrará no gráfico os valores zerados.